# List out strings which are substrings of other strings in the list

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a list of names like so:

```
dog_bone
dog_collar
dragon
cool_dragon
lion
lion_trainer
dog
```

I need to extract out names that appear in other names like so:

```
dragon
lion
dog
```

I looked through the `uniq` man page, but it seems to compare entire lines, not strings. Is there a way to do this with a bash function?

Comment: If `dog`, `dog_bone`, and `dog_bones` all appear in the file, what should be printed out?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, then both `dog` and `dog_bone` would be printed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
file=/the/file.txt
while IFS= read -r string; do
  grep -Fe "$string" < "$file" | grep -qvxFe "$string" &&
    printf '%s\n' "$string"
done < "$file"
```

That runs one `read`, two `grep` and sometimes one `printf` commands per line of the file, so is not going to be very efficient.

You can do the whole thing in one `awk` invocation:

```
awk '{l[NR]=$0}
     END {
       for (i=1; i<=NR; i++)
         for (j=1; j<=NR; j++)
           if (j!=i && index(l[j], l[i])) {
             print l[i]
             break
           }
     }' < "$file"
```

though that means the whole file is stored in memory.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Excellent stuff :)

Comment: @stephane It would be better if you explain the awk command little bit.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Probably only what `index` does? "index(in, find)
This searches the string in for the first occurrence of the string find, and returns the position in characters where that occurrence begins in the string in."

Answer (score 5):

bash

```
names=(
  dog_bone
  dog_collar
  dragon
  cool_dragon
  lion
  lion_trainer
  dog
)

declare -A contained                 # an associative array
for (( i=0; i < ${#names[@]}; i++ )); do 
    for (( j=0; j < ${#names[@]}; j++ )); do 
        if (( i != j )) && [[ ${names[i]} == *"${names[j]}"* ]]; then
            contained["${names[j]}"]=1
        fi 
    done
done
printf "%s\n" "${!contained[@]}"    # print the array keys
```

```
dog
dragon
lion
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Perl approach. This also needs to load the file into memory:

```perl
perl -le '@f=<>; foreach $l1 (@f){ 
                    chomp($l1); 
                    foreach $l2 (@f){ 
                        chomp($l2); 
                        next if $l1 eq $l2; 
                        $k{$l1}++ if $l2=~/$l1/;
                    }
                } print join "\n", keys %k' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `bash` version `4.x` solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A output
readarray input < '/path/to/file'

for i in "${input[@]}"; do
  for j in "${input[@]}"; do
    [[ $j = "$i" ]] && continue
    if [ -z "${i##*"$j"*}" ]; then
      if [[ ! ${output[$j]} ]]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$j"
        output[$j]=1
      fi
    fi
  done
done
```

Comment: I have added your solution over here. Please change if needed. :)

Comment: @Ramesh: No, this question is different with yours.

Comment: oops. Sorry, I misunderstood the question initially :)

Answer (score 3):

A hacky way to do what you want. I'm not sure if all your examples will include a underscore or not but you could key off of that and use `sort | uniq -d` to produce a list of substrings that are present more than once within a given file, using the actual file itself as a list of fixed strings to `grep`, via the `-F` switch.

#### Example

```
$ grep -oFf <(grep -v _ file.txt) file.txt |
    LC_ALL=C sort | LC_ALL=C uniq -d    
dog
dragon
lion
```

The above works as follows.

1. `<(grep -v _ file.txt)` will produce a list of the contents of `file.txt` omitting the lines that contain a underscore (`_`).

   ```
   $ grep -v _ file.txt 
   dragon
   lion
   dog
   ```
2. `grep -oFf <(..) file.txt` will use the results of #1 as a list of fixed length strings that `grep` will find within the file `file.txt`.

   ```
   $ grep -oFf <(grep -v _ file.txt) file.txt
   dog
   dog
   dragon
   dragon
   lion
   lion
   dog
   ```
3. The results of this command are then run through the `sort` & `uniq -d` commands which will list the entries that occur more than once amongst the results that `grep -oFf` has produced.

**NOTE:** If you'd like to understand why you need to enlist the use of `LC_ALL=C` when performing the `sort` and `uniq` calls then take a look at @Stephane's fine answer to this here: [What does "LC_ALL=C" do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do).

Comment: That's wrong as it is equivalent to `grep -v _ file.txt`. Using `LC_ALL=C sort | LC_ALL=C uniq -d` instead of `sort -u` would work

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - thanks for the feedback. Can you explain what's wrong? I don't understand what you're suggestion is going to change.

Comment: `grep -of <(grep -v _ file.txt) file.txt` will always return the lines that don't contain underscores because they match themselves (you're also missing some `-F`, but that's another issue).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - OK I finally understand what `LC_ALL=C` is doing in all your examples now. I finally stumbled across your A to that Q, funny I'd never seen that one until today. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer assumes that one wants to consider whether `foo` is within `foo_bar`, but not whether `a_b` is within `a_b_c`. It also won't work if there's a `foo`, and `foobar`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - that's the trouble with hacky solutions. It will work for most situations that contain underscores as I stated in the first paragraph. Do you know off hand if you can word boundary the fixed strings via `grep`'s `-F` option? That could be of potential use in making this better, but this type of solution is something you can use in a pinch, but is not meant to be exhaustive or highly robust.