# remove blank lines in awk display

Tags: awk

I was trying to figure out a solution for [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128307/list-out-strings-which-are-substrings-of-other-strings-in-the-list) question. I wanted to use `awk` for the solution.

My input file is something like below.

```
-bash-3.2$ cat file
ramesh
ramesh_venkat
ramesh3_venkat3
ramesh4
ramesh5
venkat
venkat3
venkat4
```

I used `awk` command to extract the second values after `_` as below.

```
awk -F "_" '{print $2}' file
```

However, though the above command prints the correct values I am getting blank lines in my output. I have 2 questions.

**Question 1**

How can I remove the blank lines in output so that I get only `venkat` and `venkat3` in the output?

If I use `printf` instead of `print` in my `awk`, I get `venkatvenkat3` as output which is not I wanted to achieve. I want the output like,

```
venkat
venkat3
```

**Question 2**

Using those values as an *associative array* or something, how can I find if the values actually occur in `$1` column?

I wanted to achieve something like,

```
awk -F "_" '$2==1{print $1}' file
```

**EDIT**

I did not notice the `awk` solution of Stephane. Is it doing the same thing that I had mentioned?

Comment: Stephane's `awk` is not doing the same thing. Your approach assumes that a word can only be contained in another if it is separated by `_`. While that is true for the OP's example, all of the posted answers also deal with cases like `doglion` and not only `dog_lion`.

Comment: For non-awk, see: [How to remove blank lines from a file in shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101440/21471)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Question1**

```
$ awk -F _ 'NF > 1 {print $2}' file
venkat
venkat3
```

**Question2**

```
$ awk -F _ '
    NR == FNR {a[$1];next}
    ($2 in a) {print $2}
' file file
venkat
venkat3
```

Comment: I need to display `venkat` and `venkat3` as per the OP asked in the other question. I am trying to find if the key after `_` is present in my `$1` column.

Comment: Oh, I have updated my answer!

Comment: Nice solution. I think you should add this one also to your solution in the other question :)

Answer (score 12):

Another approach:

#### Question 1

```
awk -F_ '$2{print $2}' file
```

This will only print if `$2` is defined. It is a shorter way of writing:

```
awk -F_ '{if($2){print $2}}' file
```

#### Question 2

Don't have anything to add that has not already been addressed.

Answer (score 8):

for Question 1, you could use the `--only-delimited` (`-s`) option of `cut`

```
cut -s -f2 -d'_' file
venkat
venkat3
```

Answer (score 6):

**question 1**

```
awk -F "_" '/_/ {print $2}' file
```

**question 2**

```
awk -F "_" '{values[$1]=1;}; END {for (val in values) print val;}' file
```

Comment: For question2, I intend to get only `venkat` and `venkat3` as output as they are present in `$1`. However, I get all the `$1` values as per your command.

Comment: @Ramesh: As your describtion, I think you want to get `$2` of entry that have `$2` occurs in 1st column. Is this right?

Comment: @Gnouc, yes you are right.