# Awk select columns between html table data

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, html

I'm trying to extract data between

```
<td></td>
```

tags, but if i use something like

```
awk -F"<td>" {' $1 ":" $2 '}
```

it will output the remaining html data after column 1 and column 2, how can I extract inbetween both and only extract the data/string its self?

Answer (score 3):

This does what you want:

```
$ awk -F'</*td>' '$2{print $2}' someFile
```

This works by defining a split argument that matches the beginning `<td>` as well as the ending `</td>`. This isolates the string in the middle as field `$2`. The remainder will print `$2` if it's defined.

#### Example

```
$ cat someFile
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>
         A Small Hello
      </TITLE>
   </HEAD>
<BODY>
   <table><td>hello world</td></table>
   <table><td>hello world</td></table>
   <table><td>hello world</td></table>
   <table>
   <td>hello world</td>
   </table>
   <H1>Hi</H1>
   <P>This is very minimal "hello world" HTML document.</P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Output:

```
$ awk -F'</*td>' '$2{print $2}' someFile
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
```

#### References

- [remove blank lines in awk display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128328/remove-blank-lines-in-awk-display)