# sed regexp HEX char

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have the following string

```
echo -e "a12\x8fb12\x9f" | xxd
0000000: 6131 328f 6231 329f 0a                   a12.b12..
```

and want to delete the sequence `12\x9f` and `12\x8f` with `sed`.

I can do it with this command

```
sed -e 's_12\x8f__g' -e 's_12\x9f__g'
```

but why does this command not work?

```
sed -e 's_12[\x8f\x9f]__g'
```

Comment: I would assume that sed is not completely binary safe. You try to only work on the hex side like this: `echo -e "a12\x8fb12\x9f" | sed -e 's_12[\x8f]__g' | xxd -ps | sed 's/../\0 /g'  | sed -r 's/31 32 (8f|9f) ?//g' | xxd -r -ps | xxd`

Comment: Use `LC_ALL=C sed...`, `\x8f` by itself won't make a character in a UTF-8 locale.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would be because the `[...]` matches on a character. `sed` would try and match characters against the range specified in `[...]`. In UTF-8 locales, you can only encounter `\x8f` as part of a multi-byte character. You'll notice that `.` doesn't match on it either (and that's a POSIX requirement).

For instance:

```
sed 's/[eé\xa9]//'
```

would not make sense. `é` is a character (encoded as `0xc3 0xa9`), 0xa9 is not a character but as a byte, can be found inside a character (like `é`), `e` is a character (encoded as 0x65). You can't expect `sed` to somehow be able to match 0xa9 both inside a character and as a byte.

To match arbitrary byte data with a *text* utility like `sed`, you'll want to use a locale where characters are bytes, that's a typical case for [`LC_ALL=C`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/22565).

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/12[\x8f\x9f]//g'
```

Or portably:

```
LC_ALL=C sed "$(printf 's/12[\217\237]//g')"
```

Note that you can't expect to process data containing NUL characters (or that don't end in a newline character or where newline characters are more than a few kilobytes appart) portably with `sed`. Use `perl -p/-n` instead in that case.