# Print lines if given column starts with a capital letter

Tags: awk

I have a file like this:

```
ID  A56
DS  /A56
DS  AGE 56
```

And I'd like to print the whole line only if the second column starts with a capital letter.

Expected output:

```
ID  A56
DS  AGE 56
```

What I've tried so far:
`awk '$2 ~ /[A-Z]/ {print $0}' file`
Prints everything: capital letters are found within the second column.

`awk '$2 /[A-Z]/' file`
Gets a syntax error.

Comment: You might also want to check out [SwissKnife](http://swissknife.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: You just needed to add the hat `awk '$2~/^[A-Z]/' file`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `awk` as @cuonglm suggested, or

1. GNU grep

   ```
   grep -P '^[^\s]+\s+[A-Z]' file
   ```
2. Perl

   ```
   perl -lane 'print if $F[1]=~/^[A-Z]/' file
   ```
3. GNU sed

   ```
   sed -rn '/^[^\s]+\s+[A-Z]/p' file
   ```
4. shell (assumes a recent version of ksh93, zsh or bash)

   ```
   while read -r a b; do 
       [[ $b =~ ^[A-Z] ]] && printf "%s %s\n" "$a" "$b"; 
   done < file
   ```

Comment: That assumes GNU `grep`, GNU `sed` and for the last one, recent versions of ksh93 zsh or bash and that the file doesn't contain backslash characters. Except for the `perl` one what `[A-Z]` matches depends on the locale and doesn't make much sense except in the C locale.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas so `-P` is a GNU extension? OK. Why does the `[A-Z]` not make sense? Presumably, the OP would want whatever is defined as a capital letter in their locale right? I added `-r` for the backslashes.

Comment: backslashes still an issue with Unix-conformant echos. Yes `-P` is a GNU extension though it's found as well in some BSDs that have forked or rewritten their GNU grep. See [there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/22565) for `[A-Z]`. Also note that `\s` is `[[:space:]]`, not `[[:blank:]]`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I see, thanks. I switched to `printf` then, just in case.

Answer (score 11):

You must use regex `^` to denote start of string:

```
$ awk '$2 ~ /^[[:upper:]]/' file
ID  A56
DS  AGE 56
```