# Matching string with a fixed number of characters using grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am trying to find all `6` letter words using `grep`. I currently have this:

```
grep "^.\{6\}$" myfile.txt
```

However, I am finding that I am also getting results such as: `étuis`, `étude`.

I suspect it has something do with the symbols above the `e` in the above words.

Is there something I can do to ensure that this does not happen?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

`grep`'s idea of a character [is locale-dependent](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html#tag_20_55_08). If you're in a non-Unicode locale and you grep from a file with Unicode characters in it then the character counts won't match up. If you `echo $LANG` then you'll see the locale you're in.

If you set the `LC_CTYPE` and/or `LANG` environment variables to a value ending with ".UTF-8" then you will get the right behaviour:

```
$ cat data
étuis
letter
éééééé
$ LANG=C grep -E '^.{6}$' data
étuis
letter
$ LANG=en_US.UTF_8 grep -E '^.{6}$' data
letter
éééééé
$
```

You can change your locale for just a single command by assigning the variable on the same line as the command.

With this configuration, multi-byte characters are considered as single characters. If you want to exclude non-ASCII characters entirely, some of the other answers have solutions for you.

---

Note that it's still possible for things to break, or at least not do exactly what you expect, in the presence of [combining characters](http://www.unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html). Your `grep` may treat LATIN SMALL LETTER E + COMBINING CHARACTER ACUTE ABOVE differently than LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE.

Comment: if you use `.`, something like `wăsd's` will match

Comment: `'` is a character that can reasonably be part of a "string with a fixed number of characters".

Comment: Maybe. And you should set both `LC_CTYPE` and `LANG`, something like `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US` will be failed. Use `LC_ALL` for safety.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `grep` when built with PCRE support, you can do:

```
grep -Px '\X{6}'
```

While `.` matches a character, `\X` matches an ideogram/graphem.

In a UTF-8 locale:

```
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
$ printf '\u00e9tuis\n\u00e9tudes\n' | grep -Px '\X{6}'
études
$ printf 'e\u0301tuis\ne\u0301tudes\n' | grep -Px '\X{6}'
études
```

In that latter `études`, there are 7 characters, 8 bytes, and 6 graphems.

Comment: It seems does not work: `echo épée | grep -Px '\X{6}'`
ouput `épée`

Comment: @Gnouc, you need to run that in a UTF-8 locale (if those `é` above were encoded in UTF-8).

Comment: Oh, my mistakes. It works with UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 grep -x '[_[:alnum:]]\{6\}' file
```

`-x` use to match whole line, and defined by POSIX (See [grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html)).

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do) for good explanation of what `LC_ALL` does. You can set `LANG` or `LC_CTYPE` to use utf-8 to get the same behaviour. The order taking affect is `LC_ALL` => `LANG` => `LC_CTYPE`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

`grep "^[A-Za-z]\{6\}$" myfile.txt`

or if the words may contain numbers too, then:

`grep "^[A-Za-z0-9]\{6\}$" myfile.txt`

Just add any characters to the square brackets that you want in addition to these.

Comment: This won't match the `étude` at all, because the ASCII character corresponding to the accent will mess up the regex.