# Find a file where name starts with a capital letter

Tags: find

I'm trying to find all files for which there name starts with a capital letter. I have tried using the following command:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*\/[A-Z][^/]*'
```

It's finding paths with only lowercase letters.  The following works:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*\/[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][^/]*'
```

As does:

```
find . -type f | grep '.*\/[A-Z][^/]*$'
```

I've tried all the different options for `regextype`, with the same result.

Why does `find` include lowercase letters in `[A-Z]`?  I thought the regex for that was `[a-zA-Z]`.  Is there any way to specify a range of only uppercase letters in `find`?

Comment: What about `LC_ALL=C find ...`?

Comment: That works.  Could you explain why in an answer?

Comment: I could try, but then you [might miss out on this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/52934).

Comment: Why are you escaping the slash (`\/`)? Also what **find** are you using (`find --version`)?

Comment: The version is GNU 4.4.2.  Escaping the slash is just an old habit from perl or somewhere, I guess.

Comment: The Unicode standard has something interesting about [locale-dependent ranges](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/tr18-5.1.html#Locale%20Dependent%20Ranges): "Locale-dependent character ranges will include locale-dependent graphemes, as discussed above. This broadens the set of graphemes — in traditional Spanish, for example, `b-d` would match against `ch`. Languages may also vary whether they consider lowercase below uppercase or the reverse. This can have some surprising results: [a-Z] may not match anything if Z < a in that locale!". By the way, what does the `locale` command say?

Comment: `locale` shows `en_US.UTF-8` for everything.

Comment: Escaping `/` is only necessary when you're using it as a delimiter, e.g. in `s/foo\/bar/foobar/`. (But often you can use some other delimiter: `s#foo/bar#foobar#`.)

Answer (score 42):

You don't need to use `-regex`. You can use `-name` instead.

```
find . -type f -name "[[:upper:]]*"
```

Comment: If I wanted to use `-regex` instead of `-name`, what’s the correct syntax for it?