# Bash limiting precision of floating point variables

Tags: bash, bc, floating-point

In Ubuntu `14.04.1 LTS 64-bit` bash I am declearing floating point variables by multiplying floating point bash variables in `bc` with scale set to 3; however, I cannot get the number of digits after the decimal point to be zero and get rid of the zero to the left of the decimal point. How can I transform, say `0.005000000` into `.005`? This is necessary due to my file naming convention. Thanks for your recommendations.

UPDATE: Can I use it for already defined shell variables and redefining them? The following code gives me an error.

```
~/Desktop/MEEP$ printf "%.3f\n" $w
bash: printf: 0.005000: invalid number
0,000
```

The output of locale

```
@vesnog:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

The output of `echo $w`

```
@vesnog:~$ echo $w
0.005000
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simple way is to use `printf`:

```
$ printf "%.3f\n" 0.005000000000
0.005
```

To remove the leading `0`, just parse it out with `sed`:

```
$ printf "%.3f\n" 0.005000000000 | sed 's/^0//'
.005
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can I use the same setup with an already assigned variable like I described in the edit of my OP?

Comment: I think I am having difficulties with the delimiter for the decimal point, is there an easy way to set it? It even says invalid number in the examples you provided in this post.

Comment: @Vesnog please [edit] your question and include your locale. It looks like you're using a locale with comma as a decimal separator instead of dot.

Comment: Where can I find this file?

Comment: I'm not at my computer, so I can't check now, but it should be in the output of `locale`. Also show us the output of `echo $w`.

Comment: I updated the question accordingly. I also checked setting `w` with a comma as a decimal point separator and it worked in printf statement.

Answer (score 11):

There is a special variable called `scale`. You can set this variable to limit the precision.

**EXAMPLE**

```
$ echo "300/7" | bc -l
42.85714285714285714285
```

To limit the precision,

```
$ echo "scale=2; 300/7" | bc -l
42.85
```

**UPDATED**

```
$ echo "scale=3; 300/7" | bc -l | sed 's/[0-9]*\././g'
.857
```

Comment: I up-vote because this is the answer to the question that I googled.

Answer (score 0):

This sed command removes trailing zeros:

```
sed 's/\(0\.0*[1-9][1-9]*\)0*/\1/'
```

It remembers any values beginning with `0.`, followed by zero or more `0`'s, followed by 1 or more digits from 1-9, followed by zero or more `0`'s. It then truncates the zero or more trailing `0`'s.

This allows you to parse out an arbitrary number of trailing zeros, and retain any arbitrarily low number greater than zero. regardless of how small it is.

For example

`0.054000` becomes `0.054`, or `0.00000010000000` becomes `0.0000001`, and so on.

For more info check out Grymoires awesome [sed](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but for any new people who google this problem.
Invalid number hasn't been solved from the OP in the most voted answer, in fact the answer also gives me an invalid number error.

Reason is `LC_NUMERIC` variable from locale. Simple solution: use "," instead of "." as a decimal point. Also simple, change the locale variable.

Test it

```
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Permanent

```
echo 'export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"' >>~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Good point for calling out the locale issue but note that not every system has a `en_US.UTF-8` locale, every system has a `C` locale though (where the numerical radix is also `.`; and more generally a lot of the locale convention align with the US-english ones). Also note that `LC_ALL` if set would take precedence over `LC_NUMERIC`. See also [What does "LC\_ALL=C" do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87745)

Answer (score 0):

Why not grep?

```
echo "$your_number" | grep -o '.*[1-9]'
```

Comment: The question is a little unclear,  but it seems that the OP wants to chop a number to three decimal places, not remove trailing zeroes,  so 0.123456000 should become 0.123 (not 0.123456), and 1.500000000 should become 1.500 (not 1.5).