# Output of process substitution in bash duplicates ^A characters

Tags: bash

I recently wrote a script where I wanted to modify a file with sed before passing it as a parameter to another command:

```
$ some-command <(sed $'s\x01foo\x01bar\x01g' some-file)
```

This failed with the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unknown option to `s'
```

After some experimentation, I found that bash was duplicating the `^A` (`\x01`) character before calling sed:

```
$ cat -v <(echo $'\x01')
^A^A
```

This does not happen with ^B (or other) characters.

```
$ cat -v <(echo $'\x02')
^B
```

Where is this behaviour documented?  Is it a result of some default setting where ^A is used for obscure functionality?

I'm seeing this in four different versions of bash that I have access to: 4.1.2, 4.2.25, 4.2.46 (linux) and 4.3.42 (cygwin)

Comment: i found this answer about a similar question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195081/bash-regular-expression-comparison-fail-for-hex-byte-x01
hope it helps.

Comment: That's one of several bugs that involved the 0x1 character in bash (used internally to encode special data). That one was fixed in 4.4.

Comment: It still happens in 4.4 here.

Comment: @isaac, OK sorry,  I was testing with an earlier build of the development version not 4.4. The point is that it has been reported and fixed already

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Your first comment is the answer I would accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been [reported as a bug last February](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-02/msg00033.html) and again last September. There's a note about [a fix in the Bash git tree](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-09/msg00042.html) in the latter discussion.

It happens with both `^A`/`\001` and with DEL/`^?`/`\177`, but seems to require `$'...'` inside the process substitution, so you could work around it by using `"$(printf "...")"` instead:

Not ok:

```
$ od -c  <( echo -n  $'\x01_\x7f' ) 
0000000 001 001   _ 001 177
0000005
```

Ok:

```
$ od -c  <( echo -n  "$(printf '\x01_\x7f')" )
0000000 001   _ 177
0000003
```

Comment: You may omit the echo, just do `od -c  <( printf '\x01_\x7f' )`.

Comment: @isaac, well, the `echo` is there just for demonstration. The point is that command substitution + printf works as a replacement.

Comment: Interesting that `DEL` also causes this behaviour.  I didn't bother to check all the possibilities.  It looks like `\1` is being used to escape `\?` internally for some reason and the escapes are leaking out of the abstraction.

Comment: @AdrianPronk, yep, something like that. There was another one regarding `$*` some months ago: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-11/msg00107.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `\x01` is duplicated when used inside parameter expansion:

```
$ cat -v <(echo $'\x01')
^A^A
```

And it happens in versions of bash after 2.05:

```
$ ./script
zsh/sh          : ^A
b203sh          : ^A
b204sh          : ^A
b205sh          : ^A
b30sh           : ^A^A
b32sh           : ^A^A
b41sh           : ^A^A
b42sh           : ^A^A
b43sh           : ^A^A
b44sh           : ^A^A
ksh93           : ^A
attsh           : ^A
zsh/ksh         : ^A
zsh             : ^A
```

That doesn't happen in a pipe:

```
$ echo $'\x01' | cat -v
^A
```

#### Workaround:

So, maybe you can re-write your code to:

```
$ echo $'\x01' | some-command
```

Or:

```
$ some-command <(sed $'s\x02foo\x02bar\x02g' some-file)
```

Comment: I ended up just using `/` as the delimiter and ensuring that it would be escaped correctly in the pattern and replacement strings