# Why doesn't grep return what I expect when I use single quotes

Tags: grep, quoting, options

**I have a file with the below contents:**

```
sh-4.2$ cat file1
example of multiple
pattern
this is an
example of multipole
sorry multiple
pattern matching
using grep
so the example is the
file itself
-example
-multiple
-bye
tata
!
```

While searching for "-example" in the above file, the grep command is not giving the desired output. I know if the pattern contains '-' then -e option should be used:

In the first example I used *-example* directly without any quotes:

```
sh-4.2$ grep -example file1
example of multiple
example of multipole
so the example is the
-example
```

*-example* with single quotes:

```
sh-4.2$ grep '-example' file1
example of multiple
example of multipole
so the example is the
-example
```

*-example* with double quotes and escape characters

```
sh-4.2$ grep "\-example" file1
-example
sh-4.2$
```

Comment: What is the desired output? Seems that grep works ok by your tests.

Comment: when using double quotes with escape sequence , i am getting the desired output, but when i use single quotes the desired output is not coming

Comment: So the question is about single vs double quotes in grep and bash gemerally... big story.

Comment: yup.. that's what it is about

Comment: google "bash single or double quotes".... a lot of info exists even in this community.

Comment: So, what exactly is the question? "Why doesn't grep return what I expect when I use single quotes?" or "How do I do this using single quotes with grep?" @Pankaj-Pandey, could you edit the question to make it clearer what it is you're asking?

Comment: No question asked, mere statement.

Comment: @JohnN the question is "Why doesn't grep return what I expect when I use single quotes?"

Comment: Could you edit the question to make it clearer what it is you're asking? i.e. edit the question to say "Why doesn't grep return what I expect when I use single quotes?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you know that the search pattern contains a '-', and you know that when the search pattern contains a '-' you need to use the `-e` flag. Since you're not using the `-e` flag the shell is interpreting your "pattern" as an argument (and a parameter) instead. You can see that with:

```
$ grep "-foo" file1
grep: oo: No such file or directory
```

By extension, your code `grep "-example" file1` is telling the shell that you want to run `grep` with the `-e` argument and a parameter "xample".

This is the same problem we run into when we try something like `rm -my-silly-file-name` - it won't work, and we need to use something like `rm ./-my-silly-file-name` instead. Another workaround would be `rm -- -my-silly-file-name`. We can use that idiom here:

```
$ grep -- "-example" < file1
-example
```

The "--" tells the shell that everything after it is *not* an argument.

Alternatively, you can simply escape the "-" with a "\", as you've seen:

```
grep "\-example" file1
```

[This article goes into some details about quoting](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/rg1/teaching/unixffb-ss98/quoting-guide.html#para:sh-golden-rules): the relevant part is *Parameters and backquoted commands that should be interpreted by the shell are enclosed in double quotes.* When you use double-quotes, the contents are interpreted by the shell.

Answer (score 2):

You "know if the pattern [begins with] '-' then -e option should be used" but you are not using it when you should. `grep -e -example file1` will give you the expected result.

Here is what is actually executed in each of your examples:

- `grep -example file1` => `grep -e xample file1` (-e is necessary)
- `grep '-example' file1` => `grep -e xample file1` (-e is necessary)
- `grep "\-example" file1` => `grep \-example file1` (-e is not necessary)

Answer (score 2):

An argument that starts with `-` is taken as an option.

In your first two cases, the first argument passed to `grep` is `-example`, which `grep` understands as `-e xample` (`xample` argument to the `-e` option, so search for `xample`).

In the third case `\-example` is passed to `grep`. As it doesn't start with `-`, it's not taken as an option. It's taken as a regexp instead. However the behaviour for `\-` is unspecified as per POSIX, so you have no guarantee as to what it matches. With most `grep` implementations, `\-` will match a `-`, however you can imagine `grep` implementations where `\-` may be a special operator (see for instance GNU `grep` where `\+` is a special operator and doesn't match a literal `+`).

If you want `-example` not to be taken as an option, you need either:

- `grep -- -example file`. The `--` marks the end of options. Anything after it is a non-option (so the first argument the pattern to search and the rest the list of files to look in).
- `grep -e -example file`. Here, `-example` is taken as the argument to the `-e` option.

That's the kind of reason why you should get used to writing:

```
grep -e "$pattern" file
```

Or

```
grep -- "$pattern" file
```

if you can't guarantee `$pattern` won't start with `-`.

Note that here, you could also write it:

```
grep '[-]example' file
```

Though see [Bracket expression (without ranges) matching unexpected character in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/194157) about possible complications with that approach.