# Replace non-printable characters in perl and sed

Tags: sed, perl

I need to replace some non-printable characters with spaces in file.

Specifically, all characters from `0x00` up to `0x1F`, except `0x09` (TAB), `0x0A` (new line), `0x0D` (CR)

Up until now, I just needed to replace `0x00` character. Since my previous OS was AIX (without GNU commands), I can't use `sed` (well, I can but it had some limitations). So, I found next command using `perl`, which worked as expected:

```
perl -p -e 's/\x0/ /g' $FILE_IN > $FILE_OUT
```

Now I'm working on Linux, so I expected to be able to use `sed` command.

My questions:

- Is this command appropriate to replace those characters? I tried, and it seems to work, but I want to make sure:

  ```
  perl -p -e 's/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F]/ /g' $FILE_IN > $FILE_OUT
  ```
- I thought `perl -p` works as `sed`. So, why does the previous command work (at least, it doesn't fail), and next one doesn't?

  ```
  sed -e 's/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F]/ /g' $FILE_IN > $FILE_OUT
  ```

  It tells me:

  > sed: -e expression #1, char 34: Invalid collation character

Comment: `perl -p` prints end product of `stdin` after doing the operations you desire, in this case it's just replacement. `sed`'s regex might be different than `perl`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's a typical job for `tr`:

```
LC_ALL=C tr '\0-\10\13\14\16-\37' '[ *]' < in > out
```

In your case, it doesn't work with `sed` because you're in a locale where those ranges don't make sense. If you want to work with byte values as opposed to characters and where the order is based on the numerical value of those bytes, your best bet is to [use the C locale](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763). Your code would have worked with `LC_ALL=C` with GNU `sed`, but using `sed` (let alone `perl`) is a bit overkill here (and those `\xXX` are not portable across `sed` implementations while this `tr` approach is POSIX).

You can also trust your locale's idea of what *printable* characters are with:

```
tr -c '[:print:]\t\r\n' '[ *]'
```

But with GNU `tr` (as typically found on Linux-based systems), that only works in locales where characters are single-byte (so typically, not UTF-8).

In the C locale, that would also exclude DEL (0x7f) and all byte values above (not in ASCII).

In UTF-8 locales, you could use GNU `sed` which doesn't have the problem GNU `tr` has:

```
sed 's/[^[:print:]\r\t]/ /g' < in > out
```

(note that those `\r`, `\t` are not standard, and GNU `sed` won't recognize them if `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment (will treat them as backslash, r and t being part of the set as POSIX requires)).

It would not convert bytes that don't form valid characters if any though.

Comment: I understand what `tr` command does. I _understand_ (more or less) what `LC_ALL = C` is, but not all together. Nevertheless `tr -d` removes those characters, but I want to replace with spaces. Sorry, title was wrong. I just realized, when @don_crissti modified.

Comment: @Albert, sorry. See the edit and the link I added.

Comment: I not sure sure about encoding. That file comes from a HOST environment, which uses EBCDIC encoding, and it is transferred to Linux using `XCOM`. For instance, non ASCII-characters like `É` are codified (using `od -xa`) as `0xC9`, so I guess it would be `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: @Albert, probably. You can use `locale -a` to see if there are locales with iso8859-1 as the charset on your system and use `LC_CTYPE=<that-locale> tr ...[:print:]...` to convert non-printables in that locale. Or you can use iconv to convert those files to your locale's charset.

Comment: I think it's not needed, because  my locale's charset is set to `LC_ALL=en_US.iso88591`. So, your command (`tr -c '[:print:]\t\r\n' '[ *]'`) works perfectly without modifying locale or converting file. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does it mean "r and t being part of the set as POSIX requires"?

Comment: @robertspierre, POSIX requires that `[\r\t]` match on either backslash, `r` or `t`. Matching on either the CR or TAB control character as the GNU implementation of `sed` does is forbidden by the POSIX specification. That's why GNU sed doesn't do it when in POSIX mode.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to send a notification via libnotify, with content that may contain unprintable characters.  The existing solutions did not quite work for me (using a whitelist of characters using `tr` works, but strips any multi-byte characters).

Here is what worked, while passing the  test:

```
message=$(iconv --from-code=UTF-8 -c <<< "$message")
```