# Removing characters with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, ksh, aix

I am working on AIX unix and trying to remove non-printable characters from file the data looks like `Caucasian male lives in Arizona w/ fiancÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂ` in file when I view in Notepad++ using UTF-8 encoding. When I try to view file in unix I get ^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒ instead of the special characters.

I want to replace all those special characters with space.

I tried sed `'s/[^[:print:]]/ /g' file` but it does not remove those characters.My locale are listed below when I run `locale -a`

```
C
POSIX
en_US.8859-15
en_US.ISO8859-1
en_US
```

I even tried `sed -e 's/[^ -~]/ /g' file` and it did not remove the characters.

I see that others stackflow answers used `UTF-8` locale with GNU sed and this worked but I do not have that locale.

Also I am using `ksh`.

Comment: `Ã` and `▒` look pretty printable to me. A UTF-8 `Ã` is encoded as 0xc3 0x83. 0xc3 in iso8859-1 or 15 is also `Ã` as it happens which is printable, 0x83 would be a control character in both though

Comment: Possible dublicate https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201751/replace-non-printable-characters-in-perl-and-sed

Comment: @Goro Yes at this point its is possibly a duplicate now that I understand to use C locale

Comment: To actually show what the characeters are it is useful to show their hex values. Something like: `echo "fiancÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂ" | od -tx1`, or, maybe if your sed supports it: `echo "fiancÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂ" | sed -n l`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the current locale already uses UTF-8 as the charset (and file is written using that charset):

```
<file LC_ALL=C sed 's/[^ -~]//g'
```

Or, to include control characters in AIX sed:

```
<file LC_ALL=C sed "$(printf "s/[^[:print:]\t\r]//g")"
```

Comment: @Stéphane what does printf do here? If I am deleting all characters and saving to another file do I need to use printf?

Comment: @Auguster, `printf` is there to expand the `\t` into a TAB character and `\r` into a CR character. If using `ksh93` on AIX, you can also use `$'s/[^[:print:]\t\r]//g'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `tr` as follows:

```
tr -cd '[:print:]\t\r\n'
```

Explanation:

```
`[:print:]'
Any character from the `[:space:]' class, and any character that is not in the `[:graph:]' class
\r -- return
\t -- horizontal tab
```

Examples `based on Centos 7:`tr`is GNU and UTF-8 encoding`

```
$ echo "fiancÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂ" | tr -cd '[:print:]\t\r\n'
fianc

$ echo "get ^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒ " | tr -cd '[:print:]\t\r\n'
get ^^^^^^

echo " Caucasian male lives in Arizona w/ fianc▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒"  | tr -cd '[:print:]\t\r\n'
 Caucasian male lives in Arizona w/ fianc^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: That did not work for me I tried echo `" Caucasian male lives in Arizona w/ fianc▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒▒^▒" | tr -d '[:print:]'` and got output as some unreadable text

Comment: `LC_ALL=C tr ...`

Comment: @JeffSchaller I tried LC_ALL=C still get output as some unreadable text

Comment: `LC_ALL=C tr -cd '[:print:]' < input` works here

Comment: @JeffSchaller when I run `LC_ALL=C tr -cd '[:print:]' < file` I get `Usage: tr [ [-c|-C] | -[c|C]ds | -[c|C]s | -ds | -s ] [-A] String1 String2
       tr { -[c|C]d | -[c|C]s | -d | -s } [-A] String1`

Comment: @JeffSchaller Nvm I tried `LC_ALL=C tr -cd '[:print:]' < input > out` and it worked thanks :)

Comment: `echo "fiancÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂ" | tr -cd '[:print:]\t\r\n'` should return `fiancÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂ` as `Â` is a printable character. GNU `tr` doesn't in UTF8 as it doesn't support multi-byte characters yet, but it does in iso8859-1. In the C locale on systems where the C locale charset is ASCII, that does remove `Â` (or whatever bytes those are made of) as ASCII has no such character in the first place.

Comment: Because CentOS `tr` is GNU `tr` and you probably tried it in a UTF-8 locale where `Ã` is made of 2 bytes and GNU `tr` doesn't support multibyte characters. If you use `LC_ALL=C` as suggested by Auguster, it will work (at removing those `Ã` however they're encoded) regardless of whether `tr` supports multibyte characters or not. In the C locale, all characters are single bytes, and on most systems including AIX, the C locale charset is ASCII that has no character with the 8th bit set (which each byte of the UTF-8 encoding of Ã has as well as its single byte iso8859-1 encoding)