# Filter unprintable "block-like" characters with grep

Tags: bash, grep

I have a database controlfile on a Linux system that I want to filter out (for training purposes).
However, I am unable to find a proper way to get rid of "block-like" characters:

```
▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒{
▒▒▒▒▒▒9
▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▒
```

I've tried many ways, but they do not get rid of the block chars:

```
258     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -vE '▒'
259     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -vE '@|?|+|(|)|<|>'
260     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -vE '@|\?|\+|(|)|<|>'
261     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -vE '@|\?|\+|\(|\)|\<|\>'
262     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -vE '@|\?|\+|\(|\)|\<|\>|!'
263     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -vE '@|\?|\+|\(|\)|\<|\>|!|\^|\%|\`'
264     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -vE '@|\?|\+|\(|\)|\<|\>|!|\^|\%|\`|\$'
265     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -v '[^[:print:]]'
266     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -v '[[:print:]]'
267     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep  '[[:print:]]'
268     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -v  '[[:cntrl:]]'
269     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -v '\x{09}'
270     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -vP '[^\x00-\x7f]'
271     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|tr -dc '\007-\011\012-\015\040-\376'
272     strings -1 o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|tr -dc '\007-\011\012-\015\040-\376'
273     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|tr -dc '[:print:]\n\r'
274     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -vE '@|\?|\+|\(|\)|\<|\>|!|\^|\%|\`|\$'
275     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -vE '@|\?|\+|\(|\)|\<|\>|!|\^|\%|\`|\;|\:|\=|\$'
276     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -vE '@|\?|\+|\(|\)|\<|\>|!|\^|\%|\`|\;|\:|\=|\$|\"'
277     strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl|grep -vE '@|\?|\+|\(|\)|\<|\>|!|\^|\%|\`|\;|\:|\=|\$|\"|\&|\#'
```

Comment: `grep -v` is not the right tool, as it removes entire lines that contain the regular expression. You could try `tr` as shown at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201751/replace-non-printable-characters-in-perl-and-sed, followed by `sed`. Or start with `cat -v`, which represents non-printable characters like ^A, then also filter them out with `sed`. The problem with `cat -v` is that it doesn't distinguish between a `^` character and an unprintable character. I am sure there are other solutions.

Comment: Welcome, you want to remove the characters or remove the lines that contain them?

Comment: yes, I want to remove the lines that contain these weird brackets.

Comment: cat -v displays a following output:

^@▒^@^@▒▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<▒^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^D~z{|}^@^@^▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to remove anything except "known good" characters.  e.g. to limit output to standard ASCII characters you could use

```
tr -dc '[^ -~\012\015]'
```

That will only keep characters between SPACE and ~ (character 126) and the CR/LF characters.  Everything else will be removed.

Alternatively you might want to replace them with another character, e.g. a space

```
tr -c '[^ -~\012\015]' ' '
```

which will keep any indentation levels

Finally, you might be seeing this because of *locale* settings; eg if the OS thinks you have UTF8 but the terminal isn't, then you might see this.

So setting `LANG=C` before running the command might change the output

```
LANG=C strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl
```

That'll change what the `strings` command considers to be a printable character.

Comment: can't vote yet, but this actually works!
Many thanks!

Comment: Which version worked?  The `tr` or the `LANG=C`?  Or both? :-)

Answer (score 0):

After an interesting journey I hope this answer your question, with GNU `grep`:

Sample `file.txt`:

```
▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒
foo
bar
@▒^@^@▒▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<▒^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^D~z{|}^@^@^▒^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

---

```bsh
$ grep -v $(printf %b \\U2592) file.txt
foo
bar
```

Comment: unfortunately grep@AIX does not have the -P parameter available

Comment: @user452948 it was not necessary, it remained from previous tests. Remove it and try.

Comment: It has no effect:
BEFORE:
strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl |head -10
~z{|}
H▒DB_CHRIS
7aM▒▒;▒Q
▒'y?Yܣ
▒;▒^
▒▒X?Yܩ=
(▒(A'y
?S▒▒Fr▒
▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒

.
.
and AFTER:
strings o1_mf_d3rrgv0l_.ctl |head -10 | grep -v $(printf %b \\U2592)
~z{|}
H▒DB_CHRIS
7aM▒▒;▒Q
▒'y?Yܣ
▒;▒^
▒▒X?Yܩ=
(▒(A'y
?S▒▒Fr▒
▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒