# Matching n letter filename with ls

Tags: bash, ls

I am using the `ls` command in bash, trying to find all files or directory of length n. Let's say n=5

My command is:

```
ls ?????
```

But this would also include characters that are non letters such as period. For example, the following files would match:

```
ab.cd    
abd.c
```

I only want to match files that have 5 letter or number names:

```
five1
five2    
five3
```

But not

```
abc.d    
ab.cd    
a.bcd
```

How can I modify my command?

Answer found:

```
ls [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]
```

I found the answer but how can I make this less ugly?

Comment: (1) Why do you “have to use `ls` … instead of regex”?  If this is an actual constraint, you should [edit] it into the question rather than just mention it in a comment.  (2) If n=5, why are you repeating the `[a-zA-Z0-9]` regex seven times?

Comment: Do you simply want to exclude extensions like .txt, .out, .js, and five-char long ones like .pages? Are you really only interested in alphanumeric chars, or would q_pdf.tgz and f-193.zip also be files you're looking for?

Comment: I can only use ls for an assignment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that it's not `ls` that interprets those globs. Those globs are expanded by your shell into a list of file names that is passed as arguments to `ls`. Different shells have different globbing capabilities. `bash` has a few extensions over standard globs (borrowed from `ksh88` and enabled with `shopt -s extglob`) but is still limited compared to shells like `zsh` or `ksh93`.

With `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob
ls -d [[:alnum:]](#c5)
```

`ksh93`:

```
ls -d {5}([[:alnum:]])
```

or:

```
ls -d {5}(\w) # (\w includes underscore in addition to alnums)
```

or, if you wanted to use extended regular expressions:

```
ls -d ~(E)^[[:alnum:]]{5}$
```

With `bash` or other POSIX shells which don't have equivalent globbing operators, you'd need to do:

```
ls -d [[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]
```

Note that `[[:alnum:]]` includes any alphabetic character in the current locale (not only latin alphabets let alone the English one) and `0123456789` (and possibly other types of digits). If you want the letters in the English alphabet, name characters individually:

```
c='[0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]'
unset -v IFS
ls -d $c$c$c$c$c
```

Or use the C locale:

```
(export LC_ALL=C
ls -d [[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]])
```

Comment: Why name them individually? `bash` supports ranges, which is what the OP used in the first place.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, `[a-z]` matches the 26 English letters only in the C locale. In other locales, it matches all sorts of things, it may even match sequences of characters (though that doesn't seem to happen for `bash`). Generally `[a-z]` matches the collating elements that sort between `a` and `z`. That would include things like `á`, `œ`, possibly `ch`, `ý`, but not `ź`... See [What does "LC\_ALL=C" do?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87745) for more details.

Comment: i guess that is as much as i can do with ls in bash

Comment: This drives me crazy!  [You say](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/432660/80216#comment959216_432732) that `[[:digit:]]` will match only 0123456789, but `[[:alnum:]]` will match 0123456789 ***(and possibly other types of digits)**!*  So there are characters that are matched by `[[:alnum:]]` without being matched by either `[[:alpha:]]` or `[[:digit:]]`?  [The document that you referred me to](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1078) two weeks ago says “isalnum … is specified as the union of isalpha and isdigit in IS C.”

Comment: @G-Man, yes see how on GNU system `[[:alpha:]]` matches some non-ASCII digits. Yes, I agree it's a mess.

Answer (score 7):

```
ls -q | grep -Ex '[[:alnum:]]{5}'
```

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is not a great idea: see [Why you shouldn’t parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  However, the only real problem I can see with this answer is that it may give misleading results in the presence of files whose names include newline(s).

Comment: @G-Man - not really, see my edit.

Comment: It should be `[[:alpha:]]`, letters only.

Comment: @vonbrand - why ? OP wants a solution that lists "letter or number names".

Comment: @G-Man, the idea is that with don_crissti's edit, a newline character would be changed to `?` (at least when the output is not a terminal) and neither `?` nor newline are matched by `[[:alnum:]]` so in this particular case, it's going to work, at least with POSIX compliant implementations of `ls` (not busybox which doesn't have -q, not ast-open's which doesn't work properly for newline)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I don’t really remember this, but I suspect that I probably understood it three years ago.  Why are you explaining it to me *now*? … … This is the second time in two weeks that you’ve pinged a comment to me on a thread that had been inactive for over a year.  Are you farming some badge?

Comment: @don_crissti: In vonbrand’s defense, the question is internally inconsistent.  The title says “*n* letter filename”, and the body expresses dissatisfaction with the ```?``` glob because “this would also include characters that are non letters …”.

Comment: @G-Man It's just that your comment is garnering upvotes, but don_crissti's comment doesn't really explain why it's OK. My comment adds that clarification. Nothing to do with you specifically or any form of farming.

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to use `ls` in the way you mentioned,
you should use the `-d` option; otherwise,
it will list the *contents* of any *directories*
whose names are five letters and/or digits,
rather than listing the names themselves. 
Also, you can do

```
ls -d [[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]
```

but that's exactly as much typing as the answer you have now.

Also, if you don't *need* to use `ls` in your command, you could use

```
echo [[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]
```

which will list all the matches on one line, or

```
printf "%s\n" [[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][:alnum:]]
```

which will list them on separate lines.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you'll count this as "less uglier" but you could use GNU `find` like so:

```
 find -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex './[[:alnum:]]{5}'
```

though that will put `./` in front of each entry, though you could `sed` that away

Depending on what you do next `find` may also have the advantage of helping to avoid the [Parsing ls troubles](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Keeping it with extglobs (`shopt -s extglob`) you could rewrite it a little, though again I don't know if you count it as cleaner

```
ls [[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]
```

Comment: I have to use ls which uses glob or extended glob instead of regex.

Comment: @SaadA I don't think you'll be able to do too much then, I made one more suggestion, but it's not really much different from what you have

Comment: @SaadA, `ls` doesn't use globs, it's the shell that expands the globs and passes the resulting list to `ls`.

Comment: @EricRenouf: The OP wants to find "all files ***or directory*** of length *n*", so `-type f` isn't really appropriate.

Comment: @G-Man good point, thanks for the catch

Comment: `find * -maxdepth 0 -regex '[[:alnum:]]\{5\}'`

Comment: @muhmuhten (1) `find *` is rarely useful, since `find` already enumerates directories; using *another* directory-enumerating mechanism (pathname expansion, a.k.a. wildcards/globs) in the same command just complicates matters.  I guess I see why you're doing it — to avoid the `./` — but it would have been nice if you had explained that yourself.  (Comments can be up to 600 characters long.)  (2) Your command doesn't work on my system — I need a `-regextype` to go with that `-regex`.

Answer (score 2):

Build up the expression in a variable:

```
 e=""; for m in $(seq 1 5); do e="$e[A-Za-z0-9]"; done
```

Put it in a function to be fancy/reusable:

```
 alnumglob() {
    local e=""
    for m in $(seq 1 $1) ; do e="$e[A-Za-z0-9]"; done
    echo "$e"
 }

 ls -ld $(alnumglob 5)
```

Comment: Cute, but you left out `A-Z`.  Also, see my answer regarding the use of the `-d` option to `ls`.

Comment: I was being lazy. I used `-d` in my testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to safely determine the length of a string with *bash*, you should use [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe?s[]=length). `ls` alone is only capable of glob syntax, which (likely) cannot do what you want. `find` has different implementations on BSD and some Linuxes and `-regextype` isn't necessarily a legal flag. The good news is, bash has loops, and these can give you what you want.

```
for filename in *              # globs all files in your directory.
do
    clip=${filename%.*}        # excludes the first extension
    if [[ ${#clip} -eq 5 ]]    # test the length of the remaining string
    then
        ls -d $filename        # call ls to show you the file or directory
    fi
done
```

If instead you need any filename solely with five alphanumeric chars, your method and other answers will only return those files which *begin* with five chars. For example:

**Using** `ls [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]`

```
five1.txt      # matches
fi_ve.txt      # fails
a.pages        # fails
q_fiver.txt    # fails
```

To include any file with any five-character long alphanumeric string, and *only* those with any five-character long alphanumeric string, you can use `grep`'s more universal regex implementation under bash. Although I wouldn't normally recommend it, the use of the `\w` and `\W` here can help readability a great deal (where `\w` = `[[:alnum:]]` and `\W` = `[^[:alnum:]]` – but they will include underscores, so use at peril).

```
for filename in *
do
    if (grep -qE '(^|\W)\w{5}($|\W)' <<<"$filename")
    then
        ls -d "$filename"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to make it less ugly, then you can change `[a-zA-Z0-9]` into `[[:alnum:]]`, the assign that to a variable:

```
a='[[:alnum:]]'
```

And use it five times:

```
$ ls $a$a$a$a$a             ### important that the vars are not quoted.  
five1 five2 five3
```