# problem editing utf8 text file with vim

Tags: ssh, vim, unicode

I have a problem editing a html file on a server via `vim`. The file is `utf-8` encoded.

While editing with `vim` (v7.3, no plugins active) I can see umlauts and editing and saving a line before the umlaut is ok. But if I edit after the umlaut it seems that the umlaut consumes two chars while only one char is visible and all edits are shifted. I can see this only after saving and reopening the file. And I can insert an umlaut but for removing I have to press x twice (the char changes meanwhile).

I have no idea where to search for the issue `vim`, `terminal` or `ssh connection`?

remote:

```
> file index.html
index.html: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text
> echo $TERM
xterm-256color
> locale charmap
ANSI_X3.4-1968
> grep CHARMAP /etc/default/console-setup 
CHARMAP="UTF-8"
```

local:

```
> locale charmap
UTF-8
```

Comment: `vim` has various encoding settings; what do `:set encoding` and `:set fileencoding` say when the file is loaded? Read the vim help for details.

Comment: It also looks as if your environment were not UTF-8 clear. What does `locale charmap` (both local and at the remote end) say? What OS are you using?

Comment: OS is Linux.  vim settings after open file: encoding=latin1, fileencoding=

Comment: If I copy (scp) the file to my local machine, `encoding` and `fileencoding` in vim is both `utf-8`. Somehow vim on remote does not recognize the encoding...

Comment: Check if the vim encoding set manually somewhere, e. g. in `~/.vimrc` or `/etc/vim/vimrc`. What do `local` and `echo $LANG` display on the remote host?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out, that the terminal locales were setup somehow wrong. My `.bashrc` had a `export LC_ALL=C`.

```
> locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
...
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

After removing `LC_ALL=C` I get this:

```
> locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
...
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Vim now opens the same file with `enconding=utf-8` and `fileencondig=utf-8` and editing is normal.

Thanks Murphy and Radovan for some pointers. Maybe anyone has an explanation for this issue.

Comment: LC_ALL="C" was disabling all the language locales defined and it is useful by it´s own when debugging locales problems. see 2nd answer in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do

Comment: In my case `/etc/locale.gen` didn't have my international locale described. Uncommented the right line, then re-ran `locale-gen`, everything works.