# Why does default sort produce different results with same line beginnings?

Tags: sort

I am using `sort` in bash, but getting different orders for two files, even though the first set of characters are the same.

file1:

```
  "(0, -11)": "(-1.24636393592-0.992799153308j)", 
  "(0, 1)": "(149.807097864-5.44350795193j)", 
  "(0, 0)": "(17.1604053672+3.88079235934j)", 
  "(0, 11)": "(-1.59903812426-0.923768768117j)", 
  "(0, -1)": "(47.1824114723-21.6682255934j)", 
  "(0, 10)": "(-7.9306816865-1.40521728962j)", 
  "(0, 12)": "(-1.01650580426-1.04187674309j)", 
  "(0, -10)": "(-0.901802059305-0.821904477534j)",
```

file2:

```
  "(0, 0)": "(0.581223595766+0.883221459338j)", 
  "(0, -1)": "(0.0296256019162+0.632637319226j)", 
  "(0, -10)": "(0.792520325166+0.141433946136j)", 
  "(0, 10)": "(-1.20153329399-0.805695804956j)", 
  "(0, 1)": "(0.285821897179-0.508323457505j)", 
  "(0, 11)": "(0.0402120404586-1.57660120897j)", 
  "(0, -11)": "(0.476001913928+0.127280670816j)", 
  "(0, 12)": "(-0.257439911355-1.2545061217j)",
```

`sort file1` gives :

```
  "(0, 0)": "(17.1604053672+3.88079235934j)", 
  "(0, -10)": "(-0.901802059305-0.821904477534j)", 
  "(0, 10)": "(-7.9306816865-1.40521728962j)", 
  "(0, -11)": "(-1.24636393592-0.992799153308j)", 
  "(0, 11)": "(-1.59903812426-0.923768768117j)", 
  "(0, 1)": "(149.807097864-5.44350795193j)", 
  "(0, 12)": "(-1.01650580426-1.04187674309j)", 
  "(0, -1)": "(47.1824114723-21.6682255934j)",
```

`sort file2` gives :

```
  "(0, 0)": "(0.581223595766+0.883221459338j)", 
  "(0, -1)": "(0.0296256019162+0.632637319226j)", 
  "(0, -10)": "(0.792520325166+0.141433946136j)", 
  "(0, 10)": "(-1.20153329399-0.805695804956j)", 
  "(0, 1)": "(0.285821897179-0.508323457505j)", 
  "(0, 11)": "(0.0402120404586-1.57660120897j)", 
  "(0, -11)": "(0.476001913928+0.127280670816j)", 
  "(0, 12)": "(-0.257439911355-1.2545061217j)",
```

Similarly `sort file1 file2` gives a list that doesn't appear to be sorted, alphabetically, numerically or otherwise.

I'd expect the default to do an alphabetical sort - which compares one character at a time. The lists should be fully sortable without ever reaching the 10th or so character where they start to differ, so why do I get different orders when I sort them?

**EDIT 1**
Using numeric flags `-g` or `-n` still gives inconsistent results.

Sorting by the first field works as expected, e.g. `sort <(cat file1 file2 | cut -f1 -d':')`

**EDIT 2**
For an answer to my question see accepted answer.

The solution to my problem (inspired by the answer below) seems to be:

```
LC_ALL=C sort file1
LC_ALL=C sort file2
```

This does a byte-wise sort. I don't care about the sort order, so long as two files with the same contents end up in the same order, and I think this accomplishes that.

**EDIT 3**

**This is not a duplicate of the other question.** I am asking nothing about sorting << brackets. Yes, the answer does apply. There is a difference between duplicate questions and separate questions to which the same broad answer can apply. The key here is that I (and possibly others with my question) would not have found the other question while looking for the problem I'm having.

**TLDR;** They are not duplicate questions - just related questions and related answers. They should be 'linked'. Not marked duplicate.

Comment: (bash is just your shell; any other shell running sort would give the same results)

Comment: They are sorting alphabetically. You're assuming that the non-alphanumeric characters influence the sorting.

Comment: ahh - I guess the '-' isn't considered?

Comment: Is there any option that allows a 'full' sort (that doesn't ignore alphanumic numbers)?  Perhaps just by ascii value or something? Just to get consistent results in this case? I don't see it in the man page.

Comment: Related [What does "LC_ALL=C" do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87745/100397)

Comment: That's the point of "linking as duplicates"; different wording (in different questions) leading to answers that solve both/all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorting follows collation rules, which are selected by LC_COLLATE locale setting (or LC_ALL if set, falling back to LANG when both are not set). The rationale behind this is obvious - different languages have different rules for alphabetical ordering.

Apparently collation of the language of your choice skips the "-"s.

```
$ LC_COLLATE=en_DK sort file2
"(0, 0)": "(0.581223595766+0.883221459338j)", 
"(0, -1)": "(0.0296256019162+0.632637319226j)", 
"(0, -10)": "(0.792520325166+0.141433946136j)", 
"(0, 10)": "(-1.20153329399-0.805695804956j)", 
"(0, 1)": "(0.285821897179-0.508323457505j)", 
"(0, 11)": "(0.0402120404586-1.57660120897j)", 
"(0, -11)": "(0.476001913928+0.127280670816j)", 
"(0, 12)": "(-0.257439911355-1.2545061217j)", 

$ LC_COLLATE=C sort file2
"(0, -1)": "(0.0296256019162+0.632637319226j)", 
"(0, -10)": "(0.792520325166+0.141433946136j)", 
"(0, -11)": "(0.476001913928+0.127280670816j)", 
"(0, 0)": "(0.581223595766+0.883221459338j)", 
"(0, 1)": "(0.285821897179-0.508323457505j)", 
"(0, 10)": "(-1.20153329399-0.805695804956j)", 
"(0, 11)": "(0.0402120404586-1.57660120897j)", 
"(0, 12)": "(-0.257439911355-1.2545061217j)",
```

Comment: LC_ALL takes precedence over LC_COLLATE.

Comment: `LC_COLLATE=C sort` still gives me inconsistent results. `LC_ALL=C sort` seems to be better?