# Bully v1.1 showing "locale not supported by Xlib, locale set to C". What can I do?

Tags: wifi, wps

I'm trying to use Bully v1.1.

After I enter `./bully.py`, the Bully G1 v1.1 window appears. When I press the Run button, this message appears:

> Warning: locale not supported by Xlib, locale set to C

I have tried `locale -a`, and `dpkg-reconfigure locales` but I don't know what to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever your locale is set to it sounds like this application cannot work with it. You could try this:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 ./bully.py
```

This sets the locale to `en_US.UTF-8`temporarily just for this application to be able to launch. See this U&L Q&A for more on the subject regarding LC_* variables & localizations

- [What does "LC_ALL=C" do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do).

Comment: It works..! The error disappear. Thank you..