# How to sort files in unix

Tags: command-line, filenames, sort

I have files in the following manner

`ar01440_1775_17_vc00_00.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_01.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_02.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_03.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_04.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_05.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_06.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_07.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_08.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_09.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_010.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_011.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_012.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_013.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_014.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_015.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_016.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_017.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_018.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_019.png`

I need to sort them into this order.

Desired output:

`ar01440_1775_17_vc00_00.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_01.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_010.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_011.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_012.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_013.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_014.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_015.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_016.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_017.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_018.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_019.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_02.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_03.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_04.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_05.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_06.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_07.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_08.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_09.png`

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are not code writing services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the 'en_US.UTF-8' locale caused the the '010' to appear before '01' when sorting. Forcing the `C` locale for the sort works here:

```
$ LC_ALL=C ls -1
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_00.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_01.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_010.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_011.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_012.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_013.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_014.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_015.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_016.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_017.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_018.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_019.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_02.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_03.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_04.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_05.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_06.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_07.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_08.png
ar01440_1775_17_vc00_09.png
```

The `C` locale is explained here: [What does “LC_ALL=C” do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do)

Comment: May be worth noting that the `*` glob would sort this way too and that reading the output from `ls` is not really recommended (this is what I'm assuming that the user will do in the next step of whatever they're doing).

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are not code writing services.