# Sort file by row and with scientific numbers

Tags: linux, sort, numeric-data

I have a file `F.tsv` with 13 columns, the last column (the 13th columns) looks like this:

```
2.1e-06
0.58
10
8.7e-22
0.0014
0.034
9.5
0.67
0.67
0.68
9.2
8.4e-22
9.7
```

I've tried `sort -k 13 F.tsv` but it didn't work since this didn't consider the scientific notation (like 2.1e-06).

Is there any way to sort considering the scientific notation like this:

```
8.4e-22
8.7e-22
1.3e-08
1.3e-08
7e-07
2.1e-06
0.0014
0.034
0.58
0.67
0.67
0.68
9.2
9.5
9.7
10
```

Comment: If you're using Linux you should have the GNU implementation of `sort`, which provides a `-g` or `--general-numeric` sort option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the desirewd result with:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -g -k 13 F.tsv
```

Comment: Oh, I think that worked! What does the "LC_ALL=C" stands for?

Comment: [Here you have an extensive explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/338177). Excerpt: *The C locale is a special locale that is meant to be the simplest locale. You could also say that while the other locales are for humans, the C locale is for computers*

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'll have that in mind the next time I do these kind of things