# GNU coreutils `sort` behave differently

Tags: linux, shell, sort, coreutils

I wanted to sort a list of data and I intended to sort it based on its first column which is an IP address.

```bsh
192.168.1.100
192.168.1.101
192.168.1.110
192.168.1.119
192.168.1.20
192.168.1.30
192.168.1.33
192.168.1.54
192.168.1.64
192.168.1.6
192.168.1.91
```

On my first machine, I tested `sort -n` and It worked as I expected

```bsh
# coreutils, version: 8.31, release: 23

192.168.1.6
192.168.1.20
192.168.1.30
192.168.1.33
192.168.1.54
192.168.1.64
192.168.1.91
192.168.1.100
192.168.1.101
192.168.1.110
192.168.1.119
```

But on my second machine, it won't sort properly

```bsh
# coreutils, version:8.4

192.168.1.100
192.168.1.101
192.168.1.110
192.168.1.119
192.168.1.20
192.168.1.30
192.168.1.33
192.168.1.54
192.168.1.6
192.168.1.64
192.168.1.91
```

Both machines have the same locale `en_US.UTF-8`

---

Why is this happening? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Hypothesis: the first machine uses a locale where `locale thousands_sep` returns `.`. Probably it's not `en_US.UTF-8` (at least not as `LC_NUMERIC`). The second machine doesn't use `.` as thousands separator.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Turns out, the second machine uses `,` instead of `.` . Thanks for your info

Comment: I think `,` is the right thousands separator in `en_US.UTF-8`, so I would say it's the other way around: the first one uses `.` instead of `,`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I just checked that my first machine uses different `LC_NUMERIC`.

Comment: The second result is what you should expect in the C locale. So check your locale setup.

Comment: FYI because you're using GNU sort, you can use `-V` aka `--version-sort` instead of `-n`. It performs a natural sort of things that look like version numbers (and ipv4 addresses look enough like version numbers for it to work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a proper key position, `sort` uses the entire line as the key. Since in all the lines, the first three octets remain the same, the entirety of the sorting is based on the numerical positions of the first character in the last octet. Since `1` appears before `2` the octets with `100`, `101` appear before the other.

Define the proper key position and use the numerical sort. For e.g. in your case set the delimiter for the input as `.` and let `sort` to work its magic on 4th field only. The `4,4` means start at the 4th field delimited by `.` and stop at the same 4th field.

```
sort -n -t'.' -k4,4 file
```

Also you can override any other `locale` settings defined in your system and directly use the system's default with `LC_ALL=C` locally to the command. See [What does `LC_ALL=C` do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/112235) to understand why

```
LC_ALL=C sort -n -t'.' -k4,4 file
```

Thanks to [Kamil Maciorowski's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566723/gnu-coreutils-sort-behave-differently?noredirect=1#comment1053834_566723) which highlighted the actual issue.

> The first machine seems to be using a locale where `locale thousands_sep` returns `.` Probably it's not `en_US.UTF-8` (at least
>   not as `LC_NUMERIC`). The second machine doesn't use `.` as thousands
>   separator.

Comment: Your answer does resolve my problem but I still have no idea why a simple `sort -n` worked fine on my first machine but it fails on the second one.

Comment: Please see the comments under the question. I don't want to add a partial answer and leave your answer partial as well. You have my permission to absorb my observation into your answer.